# Force a space before statement-ending semicolon in Java code editor of IntelliJ 2018

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Is there a way to have IntelliJ auto-formatting insert a SPACE character before the SEMICOLON terminating a statement?

The `Settings`/`Preferences` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `Java` > `Spaces` feature has many checkboxes for many cases including these semicolons:

- `Other` > `Before 'for' semicolon`
- `Other` > `After 'for' semicolon`

But I cannot seem to one for a space before the statement-terminating semicolon.

Comment: After 30 minutes of research, I'm giving up.  The closest I could get was to output a custom XML layout file which had some non default rules.  This can be done using the export option from the page to which your question refers.  _But_, I don't see any actual logic, just hard coded rule names.  It is as if there is no well to _create_ custom rules, but rather only to turn them on and off.